# Emberjs controller receives return value of the Route's model() method?

Tags: ember.js

*I'm working on Ember 2.13.0*

The Ember.js doco for controllers says "[The controller receives a single property from the Route – model – which is the return value of the Route's model() method.](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/controllers/)"  .

I'm not clear how I can access this data.

I have a route that looks like this :

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
      return this.store.findAll('costcentrehierarchyfortree');
    }
});
```

And a controller that looks like this :

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    data: function() {
            var arrJSTreeElements = this.model.map(obj =>{ 
                /*
                 * This is the type of structure that needs to be output
                 *
                [
                    { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Simple root node" },
                    { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2" },
                    { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1" },
                    { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" },
                ]
                */
                var rObj = {};
                rObj['id'] = obj.cchcceidchild;
                if (obj.cchcceidparent === obj.cchcceidchild)
                {
                    //This is the top of the tree
                    rObj['parent'] = "#";
                }
                else
                {
                    rObj['parent'] = obj.cchcceidparent;
                }
                rObj['text'] = obj.ccidescriptionchild;
                return rObj;

            });
            return arrJSTreeElements ;
    }
});
```

But when I visit the route in question I get a console error

```
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

So I guess that using `this.model` to access the data returned from the route's model() method is not the way to go ... so what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:** Just to make a little clearer what I'm trying to do here you can see a (somewhat) similar example in the demo app of the add on I'm using . Here's the controller https://github.com/ritesh83/ember-cli-jstree/blob/master/tests/dummy/app/dynamic/controller.js and here's the template https://github.com/ritesh83/ember-cli-jstree/blob/master/tests/dummy/app/dynamic/template.hbs .

This is , unfortunately, not a direct example because it relies upon static files rather than the data being returned due to the route being invoked but it does at least give some idea.

---

**EDIT 2:**

I was able to get this to work with the help of Lux and other resources I found.

In case this is helpful to anyone this is the version I used eventually and which works. Notice that the processing is no longer on the controller but on the route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('costcentrehierarchyfortree');
    },

    setupController(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);        
        //
        this.store.findAll('costcentrehierarchyfortree').then(function (arrRawCch) {
            var idx = 0;
            var arrJSTreeElements = arrRawCch.map(obj =>{ 
                idx++;
                var rObj = {};
                rObj['id'] = obj.get('cchCceIdChild');
                if (obj.get('cchCceIdParent') === obj.get('cchCceIdChild'))
                {
                    //This is the top of the tree
                    rObj['parent'] = "#";
                }
                else
                {
                    rObj['parent'] = obj.get('cchCceIdParent');
                }
                rObj['text'] = obj.get('cceIdentifierChild');
                //
                // Add non-jstree-standard data into 'data' object
                // see this forum post for more details
                // https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jstree/qBM2ZCAkPL4
                //
                rObj['data'] = {};
                rObj['data']['cchDrvId'] = obj.get('cchDrvId');
                //
                return rObj;
            });

            Ember.set(controller, 'data', arrJSTreeElements)
        });
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, when/how do you call the `data` function? Because such a function seems a bit *strange* in ember world. I would implement this code as a [computed property](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/ComputedProperty).

So are you sure this code runs *after* the router has entered the route? Be careful, the router waits for promises returned by the `model` hook, and also waits for promises from the `afterModel` hook before giving the model to the controller. So ensure your functions does not run to early.

Also yes, you're doing it wrong. `this.model` should not be used. In general dot notation should not be used to access properties on ember objects. (note: this is only true until ember 3.1 which [does introduce ES5 Getters for Computed Properties](https://emberjs.com/blog/2018/02/16/ember-3-1-beta-released.html) in the current released beta).

You should use `Ember.get` or `obj.get`:

```
// legazy import
import Ember from 'ember';
const {get} = Ember;

// import with modules syntax when using ember-cli-babel >= 6.8.0, introduced with ember 2.16
import {get} from '@ember/object'  

// use of .get to access a property. obj might be this or any other ember object. This will work for ember objects and non ember objects.
get(obj, 'foo')

// if obj is an ember object you can also use .get, but this will throw for non ember objects
obj.get('foo')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I appreciate it. I would like to ask a question about your response. What I'm doing here is taking multiple objects returned from the backend and changing their format. After that is complete I have an array of objects with different attributes which I would like to refer in a template . Can computed properties be used that ? I think of a computed property as only applying to a single object ? I have made an edit to the question to make it a little clearer what I'm doing.

Comment: Yes, you can. And I've seen its jsTree. In general its often easier to not use jsTree but build it by hand with ember, which is surprisingly easy. But yes, a CP is what you should use *if* you want to use jsTree. If you want to have a more interactive discussion I recommend you the [ember slack channel mentioned here](https://emberjs.com/community/). There are always nice people willing to help and discuss. Feel free to ping me.